# Cannot create Windows docker machine? "Hyper-V PowerShell Module is not available"

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine, docker-for-windows

I just installed docker and tried to create a Windows (not Linux) docker machine but it failed?

```
PS C:\> docker-machine.exe create --driver hyperv default
Creating CA: C:\Users\...\.docker\machine\certs\ca.pem
Creating client certificate: C:\Users\...\.docker\machine\certs\cert.pem
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "Hyper-V PowerShell Module is not available"
```

I downloaded the newer version of `docker-machine` (https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/tag/v0.15.0) and a new error occurred.

```
PS C:\> .\bin\docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe create --driver hyperv default
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "no External vswitch found. A valid vswitch must be available for this command to run. Check https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/"
```

Comment: How did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem with the message:

```
Error with pre-create check: "vswitch \"My Internal Switch\" not found"
```

I solved the problem by opening my Hyper-V Manager and creating my Virtual Switch in the GUI.

[image: Hyper-V Virtual Switch]

Running my same command in the command line then succeeded.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that you need to create a network switch in Hyper-V Manager and specify it when you create the machine.

For example, if you create an external switch called external-switch then you can specify it like so when you create your machine.

`docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch external-switch [Machine Name]`

See this link for more information:  https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v

Comment: Worked for me.This blog helped me too : https://rominirani.com/docker-machine-windows-10-hyper-v-troubleshooting-tips-367c1ea73c24

Answer (score 7):

When you run a command like the following to create a docker machine,

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv hypervdockermachine
```

you may end up with the following error.

```
Error with pre-create check: "no External vswitch found. A valid vswitch must be available for this command to run. Check https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/"
```

Take the following steps for creating the docker machine on windows 10.

Type hyper v on windows search and fire up the Hyper-V Manager

[image: Hyper V Manager on Windows 10]

Next click Virtual Switch Manager. Create a new external virtual switch

[image: New Virtual Switch]

Crate a new virtual switch

[image: enter details for the new virtual switch]

Now run the following command.

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch docker-machine-external-switch hypervdockermachine
```

Note that docker-machine-external-switch is the hyperv-virtual-switch that you just created and hypervdockermachine is the name of the docker-machine that are about to create with the above command

Answer (score 2):

`Default Switch` is what you need!

`docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Default Switch" node1`

Comment: What is "Default Switch" and how is it better than the other existing answers?

Comment: ...the fact is that I came here precisely on the question asked. And the point of the question is how to create a virtual machine, and not how to configure hyperv. At first I was led to the first answers, that is why I wasted a lot of time until I tried everything... And I got what I need and what is in the question, simply by setting the network that was already there...

Comment: Actually this helped me! Dont forget to run this commadn in Git Bash and not in PowerShell, since there are some bash scripts in the background whcih will fail otherwise.

Comment: "command not found"

Answer (score 0):

I solved my error by moving my virtual switch from `internal network` to `external network`. Not sure why it gives that error on internal:

[image]