# Make default docker-machine manually on Hyper-V

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

I sometimes bumped into this error on Docker for `Windows`.

I have googled around and found out the reason.

As a result, it is because there is no docker-machine default.

```
$docker ps
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

My OS is Windows 10 so Hyper-V is used.

SO I tryied like this,

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv default
```

But it shows the error like this.

```
Error with pre-create check: "no External vswitch found. A valid vswitch must be available for this command to run. Check https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/"
```

I really often obsessed with this error.

How can I fix it??

---

I indicated `DockerNAT` with `hyperv-virtual-switch` option.

`docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch DockerNAT default`

it looked progress.

```
Running pre-create checks...
(default) Image cache directory does not exist, creating it at C:\Users\whitebear\.docker\machine\cache...
(default) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
(default) Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v18.06.0-ce
(default) Downloading C:\Users\whitebear\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v18.06.0-ce/boot2docker.iso...
(default) 0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\whitebear\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\whitebear\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Creating VM...
(default) Using switch "DockerNAT"
(default) Creating VHD
(default) Starting VM...
(default) Waiting for host to start...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with boot2docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
```

Finally,docker-machine works.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE     URL                        SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default   -        hyperv   Running   tcp://192.168.1.118:2376           v18.06.0-ce
```

However `docker ps` doesn't work yet.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker ps
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

Comment: The first error message doesn't seem to be related to docker-machine, but more about a stopped Docker Engine. Did you verify that Docker for Windows has been started?

Comment: Yes,it works. I confirmed `Docker for windows service`  were launched on Windows service pane and restarted too. And command `docker -v` returns `Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825`

Comment: `docker -v` only prints the client's version. You can check the engine's version with `docker version`.

Comment: Regarding your updated details about docker-machine: by default, the client tries to connect to the engine via npipe (on Windows). When using the alternate virtual machine created by docker-machine, you have to tell the client where to find the engine. In this case, the engine would run at `tcp://192.168.1.118:2376`. Please try something like `docker -H tcp://192.168.1.118:2376 ps`.

Comment: ... that said: you'll probably run into TLS certificate issues now. I still assume that you shouldn't need to create another docker engine with docker-machine and I still assume that Docker for Windows isn't actually running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually create an external vswitch and then select it during `docker-machine create ...`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51333650/372019 for a similar question.

The blog at https://rominirani.com/docker-machine-windows-10-hyper-v-troubleshooting-tips-367c1ea73c24 gives even more details about other possible issues with docker-machine.

Comment: It's good document to start study. thank you I should learn more.